# insert age of account MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, insert, datediff

What would be the best way to find the difference in the two dates `start_date` and `account_add_date` then insert into a column called `account_age`?

What I need is for a user to select a `start_date` say its January.

Then the date when they added `account_add_date` say March.

The difference is 2 months so in `account_age` would be 2,

then in April that 2 would be a 3. May 4, June 5 and so on

Dose anyone know how to do this ?

**My current insert query MODEL**

```
 function create_bank()
{
    $this->load->helper('date');

    $new_bank_acc_insert_data = array(
        'bank_name' => $this->input->post('bank_name'),
        'interest' => ($this->input->post('interest') / 100),
        'start_amount' => $this->input->post('start_amount'),
        'length' => $this->input->post('length'),
        'start_date' => date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('start_date'))),
        'mem_id' => $this->session->userdata('id'),
        'account_add_date' => $this->current_date()
    );

    $insert = $this->db->insert('bank', $new_bank_acc_insert_data);
    return $insert;
}
```

**Idea on finding account age**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('start_date','account_add_date')
```

Comment: `DATEDIFF` function returns the difference in two dates in `days` which is more accurate comparing to the difference in `month`.

Comment: ok, thanks days can work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT     
(
   12* (YEAR(account_add_date) - YEAR(start_date)) + 
          (MONTH(account_add_date) - MONTH(start_date))
) AS differenceInMonth
FROM
YOUR_TABLE
```

Although `DATEDIFF` function returns the difference in two dates in days which is more accurate comparing to the difference in month

**Explanation:**

**Example:**

```
start_date = 2014 March

account_add_date = 2015 January

YEAR(account_add_date) = 2015

YEAR(start_date) = 2014

MONTH(account_add_date) = 1

MONTH(start_date) = 3

So according to the query:

12 * (2015-2014) + (1-3) = 12 * 1 - 2 = 10 (Months)
```

Comment: Thank you, days can work for me (better even), But how could I run this query at the same time as my INSERT and have it added to my Account_Age column ?

Comment: Please post your full insert query. @Beep

Comment: UPDATED with full view and model code, not much in the controller just validation stuff

Comment: Where's the `age` field in the query? I can give you raw mysql query apart from php syntax.

Comment: yes that's a good decision. Because age is always dynamic. Whenever you need to show just do the above calculation. @Beep

Comment: will do, the query above should be fine, i may change it foe days rather than months as your right, its better

Comment: You can show the `account age` in different formats in your view page: in months, in days etc. For example `account age: 2 Months Or 47 days`

Comment: Thank you @Subtata, as soon as i get this running ill accept your answer